# Filter array of objects based on object value in subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to filter an array of objects based on a value in a subarray of objects from the WooCommerce Rest API to pull into my React Application

here is a simplified version of what the array looks like

```
    const arrayExample =[
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Product Name 1",
            "status": "publish",
            "categories":[
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "Category Name",
                    "slug": "category-name"
                }
            ],
            "acf":{
                "data_throughput": "100"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Product Name 2",
            "status": "publish",
            "categories":[
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "name": "Another Category Name",
                    "slug": "another-category-name"
                },
                {
                    "id": 35,
                    "name": "Other Category Name",
                    "slug": "other-category-name"
                },
            ],
            "acf":{
                "data_throughput": "10"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Product Name 3",
            "status": "publish",
            "categories":[
                {
                    "id": 31,
                    "name": "New Category Name",
                    "slug": "new-category-name"
                },
                {
                    "id": 32,
                    "name": "Another Category Name",
                    "slug": "another-category-name"
                },
                {
                    "id": 34,
                    "name": "Category Name",
                    "slug": "category-name"
                },
            ],
            "acf":{
                "data_throughput": "50"
            }
        },

    ]
```

I am trying to grab every array item that has the categories name of "Category Name" or id of 34. i've tried doing a filter function with

```
const filterList = arrayExample.filter(info=>info.categories.name==="Category Name")
```

or even

```
const filterList = arrayExample.filter(info=>info.categories.id===34)
```

but they both return empty. I can't do info.categories[0] because it's not always in the first spot.

I am calling the WooCommerce API from my website for these items and I can't find any other matching identifier to call other than the category name or id. Am I just approaching this whole thing wrong? I have about 5 different categories I need to call at different times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're having categories as an array so you need to access it by index.
But you're trying to access directly without specifying any index. so you can simply use [**some**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside your filter.

```js
const arrayExample =[{"id": 1,"name": "Product Name 1","status": "publish","categories":[{"id": 34,"name": "Category Name","slug": "category-name"}],"acf":{"data_throughput": "100"}},{"id": 2,"name": "Product Name 2","status": "publish","categories":[{"id": 32,"name": "Another Category Name","slug": "another-category-name"},{"id": 35,"name": "Other Category Name","slug": "other-category-name"},],"acf":{"data_throughput": "10"}},{"id": 3,"name": "Product Name 3","status": "publish","categories":[{"id": 31,"name": "New Category Name","slug": "new-category-name"},{"id": 32,"name": "Another Category Name","slug": "another-category-name"},{"id": 34,"name": "Category Name","slug": "category-name"},],"acf":{"data_throughput": "50"}},]
    
let op = arrayExample.filter(({categories})=> categories.some(({id})=> id === 34))

console.log(op)
```